# Setting regional settings in new sharepoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

When I create a new sharepoint site collection, is there some way I can automatically set the regional settings to my local settings as part of the creation process? In particular, I want to set the default date/time format to be non-US.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using code, you should check out the [RegionalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.regionalsettings%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the SPWeb.  For example, this would set it to UK (I've done this in on a Custom Site Definition):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = (uint)cultureInfo.LCID;
web.Update();
```

Comment: And to make this run on every site you create automatically, create a "stapled feature"